# Prevent multiple tray icons in Node Webkit?

Tags: node.js, macos, node-webkit

Is there a way to check if a tray icon already exists for given app in Node Webkit (on OSX)?

My problem looks like this:
[image: multiple tray icons created for node webkit app]

Code used to create tray icon:

```
// Create a tray icon
if (os_platform === 'darwin'){ //better icon for windows, correct size for mac
    var tray = new gui.Tray({ title: '', icon: 'icon-mac.png', tooltip:    'R' });
}
else {
    var tray = new gui.Tray({ title: '', icon: 'icon-win.png', tooltip: 'R' });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This does the trick.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
   tray.remove();
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I still wish there was something like gui.Tray.get() similar to how it is there for window. But this is probably the least hacky solution out there now.

Answer (score 0):

I have just fixed this by using this:

```
win.on('restore', function() {
     console.log('removing tray.');
     tray.remove();
});
```

After analyzing the behavior I noticed that you can unminimize the app by clicking it on the taskbar. This listens for that as well.